# Why is the textbox so slow in MATPLOTLIB?

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, textbox

I have prepared a GUI in matplotlib and it has multiple graphs and one textbox
The textbox receives a value from the user and the graphs will be updated. 
The problem is that the textbox is so laggy and takes a lot of time to be updated when the user clicks on it.

This is the command I am using

text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'Day :', hovercolor='0.975', label_pad=0.1, initial=initial_text)

Comment: The textbox will sure be slower than a usual text input in an editor or on a webpage. If it is unusually slow in your case is hard to find out; do you have any data or a video to support that? If you need a fast textbox consider creating it via the GUI toolkit of choice, see e.g. the [embedding in ... section](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#embedding-matplotlib-in-graphical-user-interfaces)

Comment: My textbox is very slow too.  If I hold down a key, I see updates about once per second in the textbox. (Win7/Py37/Qt5)

Answer (score 3):

The TextBox is slow because the entire matplotlib figure is redrawn with each keystroke (so it gets slower as you add more subplots and other drawables).  As ImportanceOfBeingErnest indicated, you can use a backend to get a fast textbox (see demo code below). 

Tk is pre-installed on MacOS and Linux.  You may need to install it on Windows, depending on your development environment (see https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html)

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

class TextBoxDemo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Speed Comparison: TextBox vs Tk Entry")
        self.create_ui(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def create_ui(self, parent):
        # create some matplotlib subplots (drawables)
        rows = 4
        cols = 4
        grid = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, cols, left=.1, right=1-0.05,
                                 top=1-.05, bottom=.15, wspace=.5, hspace=.5)
        figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        for k in range(rows*cols):
            figure.add_subplot(grid[k]).plot([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])

        # create a matplotlib TextBox
        tb_axis = plt.axes([0.17, 0.02, 0.81, 0.05])
        self.textbox = TextBox(tb_axis, 'TextBox:', label_pad=.04)

        # draw the matplotlib drawables on the tk canvas
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, parent)
        self.canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.canvas_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # connect event handlers
        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_keypress)
        canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_click)

        # now, create a labeled tk entry box (for comparison)
        label = tk.Label(parent, text='Tk Entry:', width=8)
        label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=0, pady=5)
        entry = tk.Entry(parent)
        entry.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.inaxes == self.textbox.ax:
            self.canvas_widget.focus_set()
            self.textbox._click(event)

    def on_keypress(self, event):
        if event.inaxes == self.textbox.ax:
            self.textbox._keypress(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TextBoxDemo()
```

Comment: Could you explain what is a "backend"? I assume it has to do with the module `tkinter`. What is the fundamental difference with only using Matplotlib?

Comment: Check this out: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html